# How to break a text at 80 chars precisely?

Tags: html, jsf, textarea

After having asked this question in the DB section and being adived to ask it here, here is my problem:

I have the problem, that I have a long text that is being read from a database. The text itself is just a one liner. The problem is that it needs to be broken at exactly 80 chars even when in the middle of a word.

HTML or other languages will make the line break if the next word doesn't fit in the remaining chars and that is not what I want. The pages are done in jsf.

For example:

```
textarea= cols: 8 rows: 3

input= break these texts

normal:

break 
these
texts

what I need:

break th
ese text
s
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: want to do in javascript or jquery as it will easier for you...

Comment: Loop through the text, and at every 80 characters insert \r or \n in it.

Comment: javascript will be the only option if you want it displayed that way as its being worked on.

Comment: Hmm do you have a rough source for that? Just as a starter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the below function  just pass the string (you want to brake after every 80 char) to the function

```
function breakText(str)
{
  i=0;
  outputStr="";
  str= str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g," ");

 while(i<str.length)
  {
   outputStr += str.substr(i,80) +"<br>"; // replace br with any line break you want
   i=i+80;
  }
  return outputStr
}
```

**NOTE :** this function will replace all the line break and insert a `<br>` after every 80 char

**[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ikivuk/6)**

Comment: That works great in Firefox.... however IE doesn't like this. Any idea how to get this working in IE?